# Apache: I want to enable SSI. Can anyone furnish an example config file?

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

Yes - Google abounds with information about configuring Apache to support SSI.

But unfortunately, I still cannot seem to get it right.

My questions:

> - Can anyone furnish me a **full-fledged** example config file that enables SSI on an Apache server?
> - Also can you please tell me where I should drop this config file (i.e. which
>     directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site is hosted at 110mb.com.

Interestingly enough, [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html#configuringyourservertopermitssi) is the solution:

> Rename all files which have server-side includes to *.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

Apache probably wouldn't run if you didn't already have a fully-fledged config file. Try an

```
apachectl configtest
```

and see what happens.